# Search Method generates an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search, int

I need to search "Courses" in the database by "CourseID" which is a type of int. I have a simple search view form that has just one text field, "CourseID":

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Search By Course ID#:</legend>
            <label for="CourseID">Enter Course ID#:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("CourseID", Model.CourseID) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CourseID", "*") %>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
<% }%>
```

In the Controller class I have a SearchCourse action method:

```
// GET: /SearchCourse
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult SearchCourse(int courseID)
    {

        return View(new SearchCourse(
            new List<Courses>().AsQueryable(), courseID));
    }

    //
```

When I run the application I get an Error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'courseID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SearchCourse(Int32)' in 'Certifications.Controllers.SearchCourseController'. To make a parameter optional its type should be either a reference type or a Nullable type.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Please help me to understand what is wrong in the code. If I change a parameter from an "int" type to a "string" type, I don't have this error.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is the route you are using for url? If you are using the default controller route that is the problem.

Comment: You are POSTing, not getting. What does the POST method look like. Fiddler/debugger are your friend.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! I was able to figure out my problem and the Search works as i needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that a NULL-value has been passed to courseID parameter which causes the error since int is not nullable.

Change to

```
    public ActionResult SearchCourse(int? courseID)
```

Please note this is literally the answer to your question. Your question was

> "Please help me to understand what is wrong in the code. If I change a
>   parameter from an "int" type to a "string" type, I don't have this
>   error."

Comment: Yes he is asking why he is getting the error. it is because of the view not the parameter not being nullable. His view is not correctly binding and sending the courseID eventhough he typed it.

Comment: When I made the change from "int" to "int?" i've got 2 errors when was trying to run the app. The 1st error is: "Error 81 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'; the 2nd error says: Error 80 The best overloaded method match for 'Certifications.Models.SearchCourses.SearchCourses(System.Linq.IQueryable<Certifications.Models.Courses>, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Sander Pham: Thanks for the hint! It helped! I just don't know how to remove the "-1" from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default route that comes with an MVC app:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

The reason it is not mapping the value in the View and on client side to the `clientID` in the  action is because the url parameter in the route does not match to the parameter name in the action. They must be a match.

Change the parameter to be:

```
public ActionResult SearchCourse(int id)
```

Comment: I changed the parameter as you suggested, and still I'm getting the same error. Any ideas? It's just a simple search by CourseID to get a record, and I stuck here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with the route that is setup for this action request?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is your view some how is not sending the courseID you type . Change it to the following

```
 <% Html.EditorFor(model=> Model.CourseID)%>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using an older version of asp.net mvc1, I don't have this helper.

Comment: Even if I have an empty view when I run the app. it generates the same Error. Is the error in the code in the Controller? Thank you!